# volume buttons behaving wierdly

Tags: 20.04, sound, volume-control

I have 3 volume buttons on my keyboard, mute (which works fine), volume up and volume down.
when I press volume up for 0.5 seconds the volume instantly maxes out (same story for volume down except it mutes instead), while quickly clicking the button increments it. This is really annoying since I would like the volume to slowly increase (like it does on windows).
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
I am using a lenovo laptop(flex 5 14are05) with ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This is not really related but,
This is probably one of the most annoying things I have dealt with

Comment: I plugged in an external keyboard and used its volume buttons and everything worked fine for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some random kernel update fixed it, the one I am currently running is 5.15.13, I also distro hopped to arch linux.